# Search using Solr vs Map Reduce on Files - which is reliable?

Tags: solr, lucene, amazon-web-services, mapreduce

I have an application which needs to store a huge volume of data (around 200,000 txns per day), each record around 100 kb to 200 kb size. The format of the data is going to be JSON/XML.

The application should be highly available , so we plan to store the data on S3 or AWS DynamoDB.

We have use-cases where we may need to search the data based on a few attributes (date ranges, status, etc.). Most searches will be on few common attributes but there may be some arbitrary queries for certain operational use cases.

I researched the ways to search non-relational data and so far found two ways being used by most technologies
  1) Build an index (Solr/CloudSearch,etc.)
  2) Run a Map Reduce job (Hive/Hbase, etc.)

Our requirement is for the search results to be reliable (consistent with data in S3/DB - something like a oracle query, it is okay to be slow but when we get the data, we should have everything that matched the query returned or atleast let us know that some results were skipped)

At the outset it looks like the index based approach would be faster than the MR. But I am not sure if it is reliable - index may be stale? (is there a way to know the index was stale when we do the search so that we can correct it? is there a way to have the index always consistent with the values in the DB/S3? Something similar to the indexes on Oracle DBs).
The MR job seems to be reliable always (as it fetches data from S3 for each query), is that assumption right? Is there anyway to speed this query - may be partition data in S3 and run multiple MR jobs based on each partition?

Comment: Seems like s3 throughput would be a problem for the map-reduce approach, right?  You'd have to transfer gigabytes out of s3 for every query?

Comment: Have you tried Mongo DB ? If I well understood your requirements Mongo offers the same thing. It's a kind of Json stored in documents and you can query your data by fields.

Comment: Thanks I will evaluate MongoDB further.

Answer (score 0):

You can <commit /> and <optimize /> the Solr index after you add documents, so I'm not sure a stale index is a concern. I set up a Solr instance that handled maybe 100,000 additional documents per day. At the time I left the job we had 1.4 million documents in the index. It was used for internal reporting and it was performant (the most complex query too under a minute). I just asked a former coworker and it's still doing fine a year later.

I can't speak to the map reduce software, though.

Comment: I am not very concerned about the query taking time but if it guarantees all the documents were indexed when it ran the search i should be fine. Is there a way to check the index state - how many documents are indexed, etc.?

Comment: There's an admin page that I believe shows the number of documents indexed. You can also run a query on all fields and all content with zero rows returned and check the number of rows. I think the (http) query params look like: ?q=*:*&rows=0  And that'll return XML or JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You should think about having one Solr core per week/month for instance, this way older cores will be read only, and easier to manager and very easy to spread over several Solr instances. If 200k docs are to be added per day for ever you need either that or Solr sharding, a single core will not be enough for ever.